# Set elements of matrix to zero with probability using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A of size mXn and I would like to set some of it elements to zero depending on the following criteria:
I go through each element of the matrix and flip a coin whose probability of success is 0.3, if there is a success I set the element to zero else I move on to the next element. I wish to do this is MATLAB and also have the indices of elements that were changed using the above criteria. I tried using the following:

```
B = (rand(size(A)) <= 0.3);
```

I am not sure how to enable this in matrix A itself.

Comment: 0.3 is the probability of success here, that is the probability of getting success when u toss a coin and thus if its success I reset the element to 0. Also I need to keep track of elements which are reset in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First search for items that match your condition

```
zero_index = find( rand( size( A ) ) <= 0.3 ) );
```

Replace those items by zero

```
A( zero_index ) = zeros( size( zero_index ) )
```

Comment: This is not what I want , I want to reset the elements with certain probability. You are just setting the elements <= 0.3 to zero which is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply:

`A( rand( size(A) ) < 0.3 ) = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is

```
I = (rand(size(A)) < 0.3);
A(I) = 0;
```

But I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: +1 if OP needs this, you can also convert the indices to row/column pairs using: `[r,c] = find(I)`